# How to gather statistics for all tables in a YugabyteDB schema

Tags: yugabytedb

How to gather statistics for all tables in a YugabyteDB schema without having to write individual ANALYZE commands?

Comment: Who pretends it is the same? It is not. It is compatible by reusing the SQL layer. I mentioned postgres because this (schemas, pg catalog, analyze commands) are the same and this is useful for both. And this applies to the postgres compatible API of YugabyteDB - this is whow the question was asked to me by a user.

Answer (score 1):

This generates the `ANALYZE` statement for all tables in the `public` schema, and runs it with psql `gexec`:

```
\set ECHO all
select format('analyse %I.%I /* current reltuples: %s */;', nspname, relname, reltuples) ddl
from pg_class natural join (select oid relnamespace, nspname from pg_namespace) s
where relkind = 'r' and nspname='public'
order by reltuples
\gexec
```

You can change it to another schema name.

On YugabyteDB database there's no autovacuum, and ANALYZE is still a beta feature (version 2.15). The following warning is expected:

```
WARNING:  'analyze' is a beta feature!
LINE 1: analyze ehr.access,ehr.attestation,ehr.attestation_ref,ehr.a...
        ^
HINT:  Set 'ysql_beta_features' yb-tserver gflag to true to suppress the warning for all beta features.
```

On YugabyteDB if you encounter `ERROR:  Timed out: Perform RPC (request call id ...) to ... timed out after ...` you may want to increase `yb_client_admin_operation_timeout_sec`